# How to reuse the test object map in RFT

Tags: testing, rft

I have already have a script recorded with Object Map and Verification point for client1 and for client 2 i am using the same application but i dont want to re record the application, only the Verification point alone changes. The same object was used.

Note:  If i copy and paste the code alone means, the script shows error without object map. So how to re use the Object map

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export the scripts from one client1 to client2 ? 
When you export the script .. then all related files .. ie. the object map/script helper/Verification Point etc are also exportd.

Use

```
 File  > Export > FunctionalTest > Functional Test Project Items
```

If you create a shared Object map (i.e an Obect map that will be shared among different scripts in a project)  then you can also export this   ObjectMap from one project and import it in a different Project.

```
  File  > Import > FunctionalTest > Functional Test Project Items
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ya.. I agree by using importing & Exporting but what is the use of Shared Test Object Map